# Odd message and processing hangs

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have a large project that runs on an application server. It does pipelined processing of large batches of data and works fine on one Linux system (the old production environment) and one windows system (my dev environment).

However, we're upgrading our infrastructure and moving to a new linux system for production, based on the same image used for the existing production system (we use AWS). The python version (2.7) and libraries should be identical because of this, we're verifying this on our own using file hashes, also.

Our issue is that when we attempt to start processing on the new server, we receive a very strange output written to standard out followed by hanging of the server, "Removing descriptor: [some number]". I cannot duplicate this on the dev machine.

Has anyone ever encountered behavior like this in python before? Besides modules in the python standard library we are also using eventlet and beautifulsoup. In the standard library we lean heavily on urllib2, re, cElementTree, and multiprocessing (mostly the pools).

Comment: If it helps, the error you are seeing is issued by eventlet.Hub.wait()

Comment: My initial guess would be that you're running into max file descriptors per process.

Comment: It probably does help, what is the message indicating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wberry was correct in his comment, I was running into a max descriptors per process issue. This seems highly dependent on operating system. Reducing the size of the batches I was having each processor handle to below the file descriptor limit of the process solved the problem.